# Bash Script Path Containing Space

Tags: bash

I just have this simple script :

```
#!/bin/bash

mainDir="EVE-NG\ Repos"
mega-ls ahmedrafat@debugz-it.com:$mainDir
```

But I got this error :

```
[API:err: 08:40:34] Couldn't find "ahmedrafat@debugz-it.com:EVE-NG\ Repos"
```

When I enter the command natively in bash like this :

```
mega-ls ahmedrafat@debugz-it.com:EVE-NG\ Repos
```

It works, but inside the script, it doesn't.

Comment: Remove the `\\` from the variable assignment, and quot your variables, try pasting your code at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: I tried to remove it,  but the path has to be passed to mega-ls as (EVE-NG\ Repos) in order to work.

I tried the followings : 
````mainDir = "EVE-NG\\ Repos"
````
````mainDir = "EVE-NG\ Repos"
````
None of them works

Comment: The script and the command entered interactively are not equivalent: in the script, the backslash is literal. `mainDir='EVE-NG Repos'; mega-ls ahmedrafat@debugz-it.com:"$mainDir"` should really work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try typing this in at the shell:

```sh
mega-ls "ahmedrafat@debugz-it.com:EVE-NG Repos"
```

Does that clear things up?  Inside quotes you don't need to escape spaces (and it doesn't work, sending \char instead).

Note that this is required all the way:

```sh
Myvar="this and that"
echo "$Myvar" #with quotes to get 1 arg
```